# Bluetooth Headset not visible in Sound Output

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

I've successfully connected my device to a bluetooth headset on Kali Linux operated system.
But, When I run audio, it  plays through Analog Audio Stereo (System Audio Output).
I looked for solution on google, I found PulseAudio , but my bluetooth headset isn't even visible in Pulse Audio 's profile list! 
I disconnected my device and connected it through  CLI configuration , but still it's not visible in Audio output list of both Pulse Audio and the default settings section.

Please help me using my Bluetooth Headset.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type::

systemctl enable bluetooth && systemctl start bluetooth

The open your settings and scan and connect your bluetooth device

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain why you think this will work? OP says that they have already connected to a bluetooth headset, which (to me) implies bluetooth is already running. Can you clarify? :)

Comment: I spoke to the user prior to him creating this on Facebook messenger. I have come across this error many times in Linux. It will connect but not sink, which then makes the settings not read it properly. The answer above fixes a restart in the systemd to be able to correct itself in the process. Once it's reconnected and the actually sinked, the user can then properly view the device in the system setting GUI, allowing them full control of the device. I'm not sure why it happens. But I run into this issue when there is an upgrade on both kernel and blues.

Comment: This answer posted by CybernetiX does not work.
Bluetooth is not the problem. I have the same issue and the bluetooth headphones are connected fine by Linux. The problem is the 'Sound' tab in 'Settings'. It still only shows the laptop's built-in audio speakers in the 'Output' tab. When you test the speakers, the sound only comes out of the speakers and not the headset.